# Multi word search doesnt show array in PHP

Tags: php

Why that code

```
$varTerm = explode(" ", $nomer);
    $termsStringArray = array();
    $termsArray = array();
    foreach($varTerm as $term){
        $term = trim($term);
        if(!empty($term)) {
            array_push($termsStringArray, "adrs LIKE ? ");
            array_push($termsArray, $term);
            array_push($termsArray, $term);  // note, you can do this part differently, if you'd like
        }
    }
    $implodedTermsString = implode('AND ', $termsStringArray);
    //echo $implodedTermsString;
    print_r($termsArray);
 $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * 
 FROM sms_addrs WHERE ". $implodedTermsString);
var_dump($sth);
$sth->execute($termsArray);
var_dump($sth);
```

Shows this output:

```
Array ( [0] => shell [1] => shell [2] => Compans [3] => Compans ) 

object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(61) "SELECT * FROM sms_addrs WHERE adrs LIKE ? AND adrs LIKE ? " }
```

I mean why i dont see words in ? marks?

If i use direct words like here:

```
$sth->execute(array("%shell%","%Compans%"));
```

i get the desired output in rows.

Comment: Because you need to start reading manuals. There's something like `fetch_` functions described there.

Comment: `why i dont..` The prep. statem. [queryString] is send to the SQL server as it is. On each call of `$sth->execute($termsArray);` you can change the values before calling it. Then only the values are send to mysql, because the query is still there. That is how prep.statm. work, and biggest benfit is reuse of an QUERY.

Comment: i want the search words to be in prepared statements, separated in the query

Comment: Sorry you dont get the logic behind an prepared statement. Read more as @u_mulder sayed.

Comment: ok ,thank you, you mean that my mistake is in the execute part?

Comment: No. Look, the values where normally send with the query to the mysql server like `SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE field1='myvalue'` and then executed. If you use a prepared statement, the statement is first send to the mysql server `SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE field1=?`, and then when you execute something the values `['myvalue']` are send to the mysql server and the real creation of the executed statment is done on the mysql server. So that why you not see any value in `"queryString"`. So if you use prep. state. `You will never see words in ? marks`

Comment: And by the way, where do you handle the result, because you dont do `$result = $sth->execute($termsArray);`?? What do you want to do here? sorry but i m out.

Comment: i have `while($row=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ` after execute

Answer (score 0):

I found a working code:

```
$search = strtoupper($nomer);
$search = strip_tags($search); 
$search = trim($search);
$words = explode(' ', $search);
$words_condition = array();
$arguments = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
      $words_condition[] = 'adrs LIKE ?';
      $arguments[] = '%'.$word.'%';
}

$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM sms_addrs WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$words_condition));
$sth->execute($arguments);
```

My problem is soved! Thank you all!